# PhpStorm freezes on start

Tags: git, svn, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I use PhpStorm 2017.2 on Linux and have very often freeze on project load with Project A. My other Project B always works fine, it never freezes.

How can I find the problem for that freezes while loading Project A?

There are some differences between projects:

Project A:

- debugging configured with local Apache server
- subversion

Project B:

- debugging with vagrant-configured VirtualBox
- git

Comment: If project A freezes, I need to kill java process. I can do it about 5 times until the project loads well.

Comment: Please check `idea.log` for possible hints (exceptions etc) -- `Help | Show Log in ...`